# How to count the number of non-NA observations of a dataframe using Dplyr R (like df.count() in Python Pandas)

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, tidyverse

This should be easy: counting the number of non-missing observations in an R data frame.

I have a data frame where columns have missing (NA) values. I want to know which columns have too many missing observations. Simple question, and in Python this is straightforward, just run

```
df.count()
```

on a data frame, and presto: it shows the non-missing observations for every column.

However, using R's tidyverse this looks very convoluted. There are many suggestions regarding counting by groups, however, in this case I do not want to use grouped counts.

I tried:

```
mtcars %>%
  select(everything()) %>%  
  summarise_all(funs(sum(!is.na(.))))
```

which unfortunately throws an error, because `'funs()' was deprecated in dplyr 0.8.0.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`summarise_all` and `funs` are both deprecated. You can do this with `across` -

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~sum(!is.na(.))))
```

Or in base R -

```
colSums(!is.na(mtcars))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `complete.cases`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(complete.cases(.))))
```